# complicated date functions - comparing, subtracting

Tags: php, perl, awk, clock, cisco

I have some cisco routers, and an expect script, which among other things takes the log files off and will store them in a database for a set amount of time.

The problem I have is that there's no NTP, and some of them are quite old, so the battery is dead, and the date will revert to the stone ages if restarted, sending them back to the stone age.

Even if I set the clock every time I run the script (daily), if the router restarts straight after, the logs are recorded as happening years ago and they'll be deleted.

So what I'm looking for is something clever to compare the sh clock to the system time, then work out the difference and apply it to the logs to make the correct time.

It is a little complex, but I think it's the most robust way
the Cisco will output in this format:

```
sh clock
14:43:41.472 UTC Tue Apr 16 2013
```

and it's log dates are in this format:

```
Jan  7 09:27:14
```

So if anyone think of a better solution I'm all ears.  I'm currently using AWK, but Perl or PHP or whatever is good too.

Comment: What if the router restarts several times?

Comment: Well, if it restarts several times in 24 hours, we lose the logs anyway, but we can still judge the difference in time accurately for what's left.
If the router is restarted though, we'd know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse you clock using [PHP strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) that will do the job for you. This will return a timestamp, do the same for the current time, difference them (timestamps are just integers) and here is your delay. You can then reconstruct the date with the good formatting using the [PHP date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

For example :

```
<?php
$router_clock = "14:43:41.472 UTC Tue Apr 16 2013"; // retrieve it from the router
$a_log = "Jan  7 09:27:14";

$timestamp_router_clock = strtotime($router_clock);

$timestamp_system = time(); // this gives the time of the system where the PHP script runs on

$delay = $timestam_system - $timestamp_router_clock;

$log_corrected = date("M  j s:i:G", strtotime($a_log) + $delay);
?>
```